# Ruby block variable scoping issue?

Tags: ruby

I'm currently up against the wall on this, I can't seem to find the error, but I think it has to do with Ruby block scoping rules. I have read quite a few of the posts here, but they do not seem to be similar to the issue I am experiencing (or maybe I am too daft to see it). I have a Server object with only two instance variables at present (hostname and OS) that have setters/getters defined.

The problem is I am defining a Server object's OS in the middle of a block reading ssh channel data. I know the channel has the correct data since when I run the script, it prints out the "puts local OS" line correctly, however when it reaches the end of the ch.exec block, the Server.getOS has changed back to nil.

Any ideas?

Notes & Code: 
"hosts" is an array of Server objects.

```
hosts.each do |server|
begin 
    Net::SSH.start(server.getHostname, user , :password => password , :port=> port) do |ssh|
        channel = ssh.open_channel do |ch|
            ch.exec "uname" do |chan, success|
                raise "could not execute uname command" unless success
                chan.on_data do |c, data|
                    server.setOS = data
                    puts "local OS:  #{server.getOS}"
                    # server.getOS = "AIX" here
                end
                chan.on_extended_data do |c, type, data|
                    puts data
                end
            end

            puts "OS:  #{server.getOS} -- hostname: #{server.getHostname}"
            # server.getOS = "" here..
```

.. and it goes on from there to start processing based on server.getOS, but server.getOS is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what's going on here, but the likely candidate is not scoping, as that would trigger some other kind of error, but the order of operations. Your `exec` block may be executed after the `puts` call further down in the code if this is an asynchronous operation.

Remember that blocks defined in Ruby may be executed zero or more times, and at any point in time. There is no assurance they are executed immediately, and it is expected that they will be deferred at least a tiny bit of time when making an async operation.

As a note, the use of `getX` and `setX` goes against the grain of Ruby where `x` and `x=` are the methods used by convention. Method names in Ruby with `=` at the end are presumed to be mutators.

Comment: "Remember that blocks .. no assurance they are executed immediately." If that were true then how would you guarantee any procedure works as intended? I am probably misunderstanding you, but that comment reads like Ruby moves my blocks around and executes them randomly. 2+3*6 should always equal 20.

Comment: When you provide a Ruby block to a method you do not know if or when that block will be executed. You must be familiar with the "contract" the method provides and act accordingly. For instance, iterators will immediately run your method N times, most async callback methods will be called once, but you don't know when, and some may not execute your method at all because of some condition. It's not random, it's mostly predictable, but once you supply a block you are at the mercy of the method you've given it to as to how it's called.

Comment: In the case you've given, that block may only be executed when the connection is completed. You'll have to familiarize yourself with what expectations that method sets. Presumably the `on_data` method's block only executes when data is received, and that is likely an eternity after your initial `puts` is executed in CPU time-scales.

Comment: @codecompleting Toronto's got a big Rails community, why do you ask?

Comment: @tadman just curious, I don't see many ads.  wondering how the contract market was mostly...

Comment: @codecompleting Not really the place in comments here for a conversation, so don't want to blather too much, but everyone's I know is short-staffed and hiring.